# Is there any one-click authentication module for sudo for an already logged-in user?

Tags: sudo, authentication, pam

I would like to find a (PAM?) module that allows me to confirm sudo in one click, instead of typing the password each time. Much like windows UAC, where the user is switched to a secure desktop where they can confirm privilege elevation with one click.

Is there any tool/module like this for ubuntu/linux?

The rationale is the following:

- My user is in the `sudo` group, so I'm able to run programs as root by using `sudo`, after typing the password.
- I do not want to allow `sudo` without a password, because that will allow **any** (malicious) program to achieve root privileges, just by running `sudo` themselves (as they would not need a password).
- As my user is logged in, we can assume the human at the desk is myself, and a click from myself should be enough to confirm my intention to run a privileged application.
- By using a different desktop session, it should be possible to avoid unauthorized access to the authentication GUI from a different (malicious) process running under my account.

Comment: You can enable root login. When logged in as `root` the computer will never ask for your password. It will always assume you are root, no questions asked! However, the risk is **huge**. I won't recommend it.

Comment: My target here is to confirm privilege elevation (to avoid mistakes or damage from malicious scripts/programs). If I login as `root` I no longer control privilege as every program is privileged.

Comment: Your third premise must assume that you are working from a remote island in the Pacific, with the nearest human no closer than 10km from the shore. Otherwise, a momentary lapse in attention could leave you open. Have you considered employing a Yubikey?

Comment: @matigo You are right that I'm taking the risk that someone with physical access will get privileges in a momentary lapse. Let's assume I want to take that risk.

Comment: What are you doing with sudo so frequently that this is a problem? Clicking some button is not going to replace authentication

Comment: If you are just purely tired of typing the sudo password, then just sudo up to root `sudo -s` and work... Set a reasonable timeout (TMOUT=seconds in root's .bashrc) so that the root shell auto logs out and is less exposed.............. OR just increase the time sudo stays active from the default 15 minutes to whatever, with the `Defaults timestamp_timeout=minutes` variable via visudo...

Comment: I understand you can workaround my issues in different ways, or that you do not expect intensive sudo usage.I'm not tired of typing my password, I just believe the community would benefit from such a system that could allow complex passwords that are only typed once. I'm looking for a discussion about my proposed approach or existing similar solutions

Comment: This is a question answer site geared towards answering question regarding problems one is having. This site is not for discussions or questions seeking opinion based answers. Please use the [Ubuntu Forums](https://ubuntuforums.org/) for discussions. You may also consider submitting a feature request to Canonical.

Comment: @user68186 That is correct, but I don't want "discussion" nor "opinions". My problem is **secure confirmation of `sudo` with one click in a secure GUI**, please type your answer related to my question or let someone else do it.

Comment: @user68186 Also, thank you for your suggestion to submit a feature request. I'd be even happy to contribute to this feature development. The question in askubuntu is here to find other solutions people may know before digging into a new one.